# What is elongated stream (code complete)?

Tags: computer-science, terminology

In code complete book, at The Data Literacy Test author asks whether you know some words(page 238). "elongated stream" is one of them. Could you explain? Is it related to [windows file streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are kidding or just skipped some parts of the book but the author stated in the book that this term **was made up** by him to check your honesty during passing the test (test was about terms you are familiar with).